# How to get the Round Trip Time in my PING using PHP

Tags: php

So i have this code that whenever an IP is ping able or up it'll choose the green line to appear on my screen and in reverse the red line. So what I am trying to do instead if the Round Trip Time of that IP is < 200 then it's green and when it's > 250 it's red . How can i do that?
Anyone help me. Thank you.

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = 5;

function pingAddress($TEST) {
    $pingresult = exec("ping -c 1 $TEST", $output, $result);

    if ($result == 0) {
        echo "Ping successful!";
        echo "<pre>Your ping: $TEST</pre>";
        echo "<hr color = \"green\" width = 40%> GOOD";
    } else {
        echo "Ping unsuccessful!";
        echo "<pre>Your ping: $TEST</pre>";
        echo "<hr color = \"red\" width = 40%> BAD";
    }
}  
pingAddress("66.147.244.228");
?>

<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo   $page?>'">
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean you want to parse the output of your ping command to get the RTT and process the result in PHP. Then maybe you should have posted the output of ping rather than code which is not relevant to the problem you are trying to solve? BTW: you won't get a very accurate RTT by sending a single packet.

Answer (score 0):

The exec function is ok to use, but you should parse the contents of the output argument, after declaring it first as an array.
Even if you added -c 1 to only issue one ping, this is the recommended way of using exec.

```
define('RETRIES', 1);
define('PING_PATH', '/usr/bin/ping');

function pingAddress($IP)
{
    $output = array();
    exec(PING_PATH . " -c " . RETRIES . " $IP", $output);

    // generic way, even for one line. You can also do -c 4,
    // and preg_match will pick the first meaningful result.

    $output_string = implode("; ", $output); 

    /// adapt the regular expression to the actual format of your implementation of ping
    if (preg_match('/ time=\s+(\d+)ms/', $output_string, $bits)) {
        $rt_time = (int)$bits[1];

        if ($rt_time < 200) {
            // green business
        }
        else if ($rt_time > 250) {
            // red business
        }
        else {
            // default handler business (or not...)
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Hum, I didn't manage to parse the output of the ping command.", PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work im working in linux ubuntu and using a nano editor .